# iPod Touch 4th Gen iOS 6 update

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

I have an iPod Touch 4th Gen that has iOS 5 by default. Now that iOS 7 has been released and this device does not support iOS 7, can I still update my iPod Touch to iOS 6 (i.e., is iOS 6 still available)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Apple is [still signing iOS 6.1.3 for the iPod Touch 4th Gen](http://www.icj.me/ios/all#iPod41). So you should be able to upgrade to it through iTunes when it prompts you to update it.

Or you can also manually update it through iTunes:

1. Download the iOS 6.1.3 firmware (from the above link)
2. Connect the iPod to the Mac and run iTunes
3. Go to the device screen
4. Press <kbd>Option</kbd> and click the Update button to open a File Browser window
5. Choose the IPSW file you downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can update to the maximum supported iOS your iPod, as soon as you connect to the iTunes you will see there the latest version available for your iPod. Just click on update.